# Bootstrap table, how to equally align each <td>?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

As you can see at the picture below, the red lines representing the unequal width of each `<td>`. My goal is the make each `<td>` align evenly. How do I do that?

**CSS**

```
.stickyFooter {
            background: #c1c1c1;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 50px;
            font-size: 13px;
        }
```

**Code**

```
<div class="stickyFooter wrap visible-sm visible-xs table-responsive" style="margin-bottom: 0px; border: none;">
<table class="table">
    <tr align="center">
        <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i><br>Home</a></td>
        <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell fa-2x"></i><br>Notification</a></td>
        <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-invoice-dollar fa-2x"></i><br>Transaction</a></td>
        <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i><br>Directory</a></td>
        <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-newspaper fa-2x"></i><br>Ads</a></td>
        <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dollar-sign fa-2x"></i><br>Billing</a></td>
        <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i><br>More</a></td>
        <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cogs fa-2x"></i><br>Setting</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Image**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using any CSS to format them? If so, please post that as well.

Comment: @Keara i've updated the question(include css code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The additional width is likely coming from the FontAwesome icons you have there, which have varying widths by default. This can be corrected by applying the class `fa-fw` to each of the icons:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="stickyFooter wrap visible-sm visible-xs table-responsive" style="margin-bottom: 0px; border: none;">
  <table class="table">
    <tr align="center">
      <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home fa-2x"></i><br>Home</a></td>
      <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bell fa-2x"></i><br>Notification</a></td>
      <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-invoice-dollar fa-2x"></i><br>Transaction</a></td>
      <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search fa-2x"></i><br>Directory</a></td>
      <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-newspaper fa-2x"></i><br>Ads</a></td>
      <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dollar-sign fa-2x"></i><br>Billing</a></td>
      <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus fa-2x"></i><br>More</a></td>
      <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cogs fa-2x"></i><br>Setting</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that `<td>` cells will automatically expand to fill the available width of their `<tr>` container, and your cells with longer text will 'want' to occupy more room in this regard. If you want to forcibly constrain (or expand) them, simply give them a defined `width`.

This can also be seen in the above example, where I state that the cells **must** be at least `200px` wide each.

Comment: It looks like the actual distance between icons is still different, probably just because of the different lengths of the labels on the icons. Maybe if each <td> had the same set width regardless of content width?

Comment: i've added `fa-fw` each of it, but doesnt do anything...still the same result

Comment: Quite possibly -- keep in mind that `<td>` cells will automatically expand to fill the available space. If you want to forcibly constrain them (or ensure that they are all identical, simply set a `width` that is equal to 100% divided by the number of elements. I've updated my example to showcase this.

Comment: after i added the css you provided, do i still have to include the `fa-fw`?

Comment: Well, you don't *have* to... but I'd still recommend using it if you want to ensure correct alignment. I'd actually include it anywhere you use Font Awesome, as there's really no downside to doing so, and it will ensure that all icons have the same width :)

Comment: understood, thanks for the straightforward answer :D